# Enabling MongoDB transactions without replica sets or with least possible configuration

Tags: database, mongodb, transactions, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

[Some background information - possibly skippable]

> To begin with, I have barely any understanding of database management
>   and just shallow experience with mongoose and node in the backend
>   realm(a couple of udemy courses). Udemy courses made me believe that
>   mongodb was still a viable choice for a database with relational
>   properties and off I went working on a backend for a forum-like
>   website. After learning about transactions, I attempted to implement
>   them in my backend, since it seemed perfectly necessary to implement a
>   rollback feature when executing an array of queries. However it turns
>   out that transactions are only possible on replica sets - which also
>   appeared to require a minimum of 2. 3 databases for a startup MVP was
>   obviously considered an overkill.

[The question]

1. Is it possible to implement transactions with only 1 database? If so how?
2. If the above is not possible, how would one launch a mongodb database with minimum configuration while implementing transactions, with the fact that the database is for a startup MVP in consideration.
3. (For anyone who has experience in implementing a production-level mongo database in a similar scenario) If not using transactions was considered, how to send queries editing/creating multiple documents to a mongoDB database safely without transactions, while not spraying every bit of code with try-catches consisting of queries to rollback every point of failure(which I considered as way too much overhead)

I have a tight deadline, and have already done a substantial bit of groundwork and a couple of routes using mongoose, which means ditching mongodb for a relational database will be a difficult option at the moment.

I think I've googled everything related to the subject at matter and even tried blogs / articles in the second page of a google search(which many including myself consider as the dark web /s).
Yet I do think I may have missed what I was looking for and an answer consisting of just links is also welcome.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a replica set[*] to use transactions, but you can create a single-node replica set for testing purposes.

The full procedure is described [in documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/), for a single-node RS you follow that as written but only configure a single member.

Briefly, you need to pass `--replSet` argument to `mongod` and then connect to it through `mongo` shell and run `rs.initiate()`.

Note that transactions aren't a magic solution to all problems. There are scenarios where they are appropriate and scenarios where MongoDB provides other functionality that would be a better fit.

[*] or a sharded cluster with MongoDB 4.2+, but this involves more setup work.

Comment: " scenarios where MongoDB provides other functionality that would be a better fit" could you give an example please

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions that the official document offers in [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/), especially through CLI/terminal, and you end up with nothing; here is the solution I found after a few hours of vain:

**First of all, I'm talking in favor of locally installed MongoDB, not Docker or other versions**

1. Shut down Mongo service on your machine.
2. Find the mondog.conf file. You can find where it is located on your OS [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file):
3. Open the file with any text editor and replace the "replication" part with these lines:

> ```
> replication:
>   oplogSizeMB: 50
>   replSetName: my-rs
>   enableMajorityReadConcern: true
> ```

4. Turn on Mongo service again.
5. Locate your Mongo shell using `mongosh` command.
6. Type `rs.initiate()`

You might be able to work with transactions locally now.

---

*Credits goes to [this article](https://medium.com/@lambouarnold/mongoose-transactions-setup-mongodb-replication-set-on-windows-71b5a9ea5989)! You can find more detailed information there.*